# Difficulty understanding the Unity animator

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

[image: Animation timeline]

I am trying to animate a 2D sprite in an idle state in Unity.

I have a sprite in my scene. I select it in the Hierarchy panel and then, in the Animation window select "create new clip" I then drag in two sprites into the Animation keyframe panel (to show an idle player). However, when I hit play, the play jumps across the screen.

I thought it was maybe because I had the "Record" function on when I inserted the new sprites, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

For some reason the 2nd sprite defaults across the screen and I am not sure why or how to remedy this.

Can someone help me understand this?

Comment: I also notice my BoxCollider doesnt seem to be moving with the Sprite. Even when I just drag those two idle sprites into the world from my sprites folder, they still jump from parts of the screen.

Comment: Looks like you've recorded the position in the animation. Can you post a screenshot of the Animation window?

Comment: Hey, I am not sure, I have attached a screenshot.

Comment: Just a side note: Notice that there is a difference between AnimaTION and AnimaTOR. Animation is used to set up individual animations and Animator is the state machine that controls what animation/state is currently active.

Comment: Click on the triangle before the Player : Sprite text. There you will see what aspects(properties) of the Sprite are currently modified/animated.

Comment: I have tried all of the above and still dont understand the issue,

When I select the triangle, it shows me two of the spriters under each keyframe.

Comment: In your animator inspector, is Apply Root Motion checked? If so, try to uncheck it.